# Does a Bowser Amiibo work in Super Smash Bros?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4, amiibo

I got a Bowser Amiibo today for Christmas, and the box says it's for Mario Party 10. I need to know if it also works for Super Smash Bros. for Nintendo 3DS/Wii U.

Is it possible to use the Bowser Amiibo in Super Smash Bros?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does. I looked up if the Bowser amiibo for Mario Party 10 works for Smash, and it does.

[image: Here's a picture!]

Answer (score 0):

To add to this any amiibo which is a different skin of one already released in the Super Smash Bros. line will also work in SSB4, and will act as the amiibo from the Smash line.